# Video Camera Controls API

Tags: java, api, video

I'm writing an Eclipse RCP that takes photographs with a movie camera.  I'm getting the video feed using the Java Media Framework (JMF).

The camera I'm using is the [Microsoft Lifecam Cinema](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&expIds=17259,27955,28061&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=microsoft+lifecam+cinema&cp=5&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=612360608989386944&ei=OyorTcvnE8L6lweIjKmBAQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEwQ8wIwBA#) camera.  Edited to add: I'm developing on a Windows XP workstation.

The camera has pan, zoom, and tilt controls.

My question is, do these camera controls have an Application Programming Interface (API)?

I couldn't find anything with an Internet search.  JMF doesn't have any methods for controlling a video camera that I could find.

While I'm using Java, I can wrap an API in another language using the Java Native Interface (JNI) if I must.

Answer (score 1):

Before going the raw JNI way, i would instead suggest you take the [jUSB](http://jusb.sourceforge.net/) route or the [javax.usb](http://javax-usb.org/) one. From what I understand, your camera is a pure USB one, so it should be possible to drive it from such an API, no ?

Unfortunatly, as I'm unable to find any kind of reverse protocol infos, it seems like you'll have to guess how to drive it by yourself.

Comment: It appears that jUSB and javax.usb work on Unix systems.  Thanks for the information, though.